# Importing default sublime text commands into a custom command

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a command that needs to copy the current file's path. Sublime Text already has a [copy_path command](https://github.com/cj/sublime/blob/master/Default/copy_path.py) that achieves this. Is it possible to import that command into my command's file? I have tried `import copy_path` and `import CopyPathCommand`. I have also tried calling the command as if it were a method on the `sublime` module, i.e. `sublime.copy_path()` but all of these attempts have resulted in errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import the command you can write `from Default.copy_path import CopyPathCommand`.
*However* it sounds as if you run the command for which you don't need to import it. Just write `self.view.run_command("copy_path")` inside your `TextCommand` and it will be executed.